# Find A non- zero vector $u$ with direction $(2,1,-5)$ and terminal point $(5,9,0)$.

Tags: vectors

Since the question ask about a non-zero vector which with the specific direction and we have a terminal point. If i found a initial point such as $P=(x,y,z)$, we cannot say that the $P$ is the answer right? Since $u$ is a vector, but $P$ just a point or $P$ can be said a vector which with the direction $(x,y,z)$, where it is different with the question's direction.

Am I misunderstand with the word 'vector'. (my understanding is vector is a thing that contain the information of direction and distance)

Comment: Where did you find the question? Is it homework? Perhaps the instructor does not fully understand what a vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is.

Comment: See your text-- it may be by vector they mean any particular pair of points with one being the base and the other the terminal point of the vector. [Sometimes two vectors are said to be equivalent if when moved to be based at the origin they are the same.]

Comment: Such a vector can be specified by giving the base (initial) point and either the direction or the terminal point.  Yes, we often refer to vectors without regard to where they may be based or (equivalently) assume they are based at the origin, but here the topic clearly determining a base point other than the origin.

Comment: Yes, this question come from the exercise question in the book https://books.google.com.my/books?id=rcEAoQEACAAJ&dq=elementary+linear+algebra+application+11th&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 1):

You are not misunderstanding a vector, the setting here is that of the [affine space](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Affine_space), where you have set of points and vector space at each point. Thus, points can't be added, but you can add a vector $v$ to a point $P$ to get another point $Q$.

So, if you have a starting point $P=(x,y,z)$ and add to it vector $v = (2,1,-5)$, you get a point $Q = (5,9,0)$. That is,

$$(x,y,z)+(2,1,-5) = (5,9,0)\implies (x+2,y+1,z-5) = (5,9,0)$$

You can probably make the final step yourself.

Comment: You're probably right about what the person really wants.

Answer (score 0):

The general equation of a line with direction vector ${\bf n}$ that passes through the point ${\bf w}$ is ${\bf w} + t {\bf n}$ where $t$ is a parameter. You can't say much about where the "initial point" of the vector starts, except that it is some point on this line. To find the "initial point" you would need to know the length of the line (though that would give two solutions).